# Getting the Path of the open Program (Open Office) (Java)

Tags: java, path, openoffice.org

I am currently working on an OpenOffice Writer Extension. 
My Problem now is that i need the Path of the Installation folder of OpenOffice because the extension will be used on many computers which wont have OpenOffice Installed all in the same Folder.

So my question is how can I get the Path of the currently running Program? 
I already found this:https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Path_Settings

but i do not realy know how to use it properly :S

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `PathSettingsTest` from the page you linked.  The following code will get the path to the "program" folder where soffice.exe is located.

```java
Object aValue = xPathSettingsService.getPropertyValue("Module");
String aPath = (String)aValue;
```

To run `PathSettingsTest`, first start soffice listening on a socket, as shown here:
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Java/Getting_a_Service_Manager